# Windows 7/8 Access Point No Authentication/Encryption?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I want to use my laptop as an access point, but the default provided tool:

```
netsh wlan hostednetwork
```

only offers acting as an access point with WPA2. I want to create either no authentication or WEP (this is all my UART-WIFI chip supports):

[image]

I have seen two 3rd party utilities in the wild for this but both require an encryption key so presumably they are using the Windows subsystem to enable the access point.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

To manually create a network profile using WEP shared key authentication

1. Open Network and Sharing Center by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type network, and then click Network and Sharing Center.
2. Click Set up a new connection or network.
3. Click Manually connect to a wireless network, and then click Next.
4. On the Enter information for the wireless network you want to add page, under Security type, select WEP.
5. Complete the rest of the page, and then click Next.
6. Click Change connection settings.
7. Click the Security tab, and then, under Security type, click Shared.
8. Click OK, and then click Close.

Comment: This is for WIndows client connections. I want to emulate an access point on my Windows PC so I can connect my UART-WIFI device to it and then perform packet sniffing on it.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any other way then what you already posted to emulate an AP via Windows without 3rd part software.

Comment: I mentioned the 3rd party software, read my question again.

Comment: virtualrouter.codeplex.com and mypublicwifi. I **do** state why they won't work - they both require a key and then implement only the same WPA2 network that netsh sets up.